# Marker not showing up on map even after setting location manually in code

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve double values (longitude and latitude) from Firebase Database and show it on a map. The Problem is that the marker does not show up on the map, I thought it was a database error but the marker does not show up even when I add the latitude and longitude in the code itself(Shown Below). Please Help me, Thanks!

I have tried different ways of retrieving data from the database and different ways for adding a marker.

**MapsActivity.java**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    //String value_latitude = "0";
   // String value_longitue = "0";
    double longi = 0;
    double lati = 0;
   // String message = "BUS1";
    Button Refreshh;
    Double latitude = 0.0;
    Double longitdue = 0.0;
    String vali = "BUS1";
    String message = "BUS1";
    Button Backkk;

    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        //Intent intent = getIntent();
        message = getIntent().getExtras().getString("arg");
        vali = message;

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        //vali = message;

        //Log.d("vali", vali);


    }



    /**
     *
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.clear();


        mDatabaseReference.child("Locations").child(vali).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
                LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(
                        dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Long.class),
                        dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Long.class)
                );
                  LatLng sydney = new LatLng(13.0640934, 80.2501135);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                        .title("Marker in Sydney"));
              mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
    }
```

**My Logcat:**

```
2019-08-15 23:03:09.134 4869-5490/? E/...lback.CallbackFuture: Timed out waiting for result!
2019-08-15 23:03:09.135 4869-5490/? E/AmazonKindle.com.amazon.kindle.services.authentication.MAPTokenCache: [WebRequestManager-webserviceRequest2-thread-1]: Retrieving of token: com.amazon.dcp.sso.token.cookie.xmainAndXabcCookies failed
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for result!
        at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.callback.CallbackFuture.get(CallbackFuture.java:170)
        at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.callback.CallbackFuture.get(CallbackFuture.java:26)
        at com.amazon.kindle.services.authentication.MAPTokenCache.retrieveToken(MAPTokenCache.java:378)
        at com.amazon.kindle.services.authentication.MAPTokenCache.fetchTokenManagementToken(MAPTokenCache.java:338)
        at com.amazon.kindle.services.authentication.MAPTokenCache.fetchValue(MAPTokenCache.java:263)
        at com.amazon.kindle.services.authentication.MAPTokenCache.getValue(MAPTokenCache.java:156)
        at com.amazon.kindle.services.authentication.AccountHoldersKt.getToken(AccountHolders.kt:119)
        at com.amazon.kindle.services.authentication.KindleAuthenticationManager.getToken(KindleAuthenticationManager.kt:185)
        at com.amazon.kindle.krx.application.DeviceInformation.getXmainXacbCookieForDevicePfm(DeviceInformation.java:137)
        at com.amazon.kcp.library.customerbenefits.CustomerBenefitsWebRequest.getHeaders(CustomerBenefitsWebRequest.java:102)
        at com.amazon.kindle.webservices.BaseWebRequestExecutor.connect(BaseWebRequestExecutor.java:536)
        at com.amazon.kindle.webservices.BaseWebRequestExecutor.openConnection(BaseWebRequestExecutor.java:200)
        at com.amazon.kindle.webservices.BaseWebRequestExecutor.execute(BaseWebRequestExecutor.java:121)
        at com.amazon.kindle.webservices.WebRequestManager$WebRequestTask.executeRequest(WebRequestManager.java:125)
        at com.amazon.kindle.webservices.WebRequestManager$WebRequestTask.run(WebRequestManager.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding marker in your ChildEventListener, `onChildAdded()` is only called for every existing child and when a new child is added to the reference that you are listening to. **So if your reference doesn't have any children, it won't be called.**

Check your FirebaseReference, you are probably accessing the wrong child.
Or you are probably using the wrong listener, if you move your code out of listener, you will see that it does show marker.
If you are trying to get the value of child reference, then you have to add ValueEventListener:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
    System.out.println(post);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

Comment: There is a reference in Firebase Database but the marker does not show up on the map for some reason. Even When I add a coordinate to the code directly